# how do i use ubuntu from the external drive

Tags: partitioning

ive downloaded Ubuntu desktop on the external. so from here how do I use it at startup (log in) on pc. I want to use it from time to time...but still keep windows 10. I placed it on the external because it has 3 times more space than on local disk.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu already? What options have you set in the partitioning step?

Answer (score 1):

## Boot Into Your External Drive

For this to work, I'm assuming you have already wrote the image to the external drive.

Before you boot into Windows, you have to change some settings in the bios. I can't tell you exactly how to get into the bios because it is different for every machine. If you need help with how to get into the bios, please edit your question to include your computer make and model.

1. Boot into bios
2. Change the boot order so it boots into external drives before the local drive
3. Save and exit the bios
4. Plug your hard drive in
5. You will now boot into your external drive

This is good, but you're boot priority will have changed. So you will always boot into ubuntu if it is connected to your computer, which isn't always ideal. So, another way is to go into your boot menu. However, only some computers have this option. If you need help finding how to go into your boot menu, please edit your question to include your computer make and model.

## If You Haven't Wrote The Image To Your Drive

Follow the instructions [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

I must say though, have you looked into dual-booting? Or using one OS in a VM? This way you can have both Windows and Ubuntu on the same hard drive and it's much faster.

Hope this helps to you!